# Copy a personal contact list to a public folder

Tags: vba, outlook, copy, directory, contacts

I made code to copy a contact list to a public folder but if I am not on the contact source it does not work.

```
Sub Movecopycontacts()

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItem As ContactItem

    Set objOutlook = Application
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    Set objItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Set objDestFolder = objNamespace.Folders("Public folder - oky@test.com").Folders("all public folder").Folders("test")

    objItem.Move objDestFolder

    Set objDestFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

The error comes from:

```
Set objItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct - your code assumes that the item to be moved is selected. It does what it is supposed to do.

\What else do you want it to do?